# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error while Ant build using weblogic 9.2

Tags: ant, weblogic

I am getting below error while I am creating ear for my project, I am using
jdk 1.5
Weblogic 9.2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error

Details of error :

```
[ear:
     [echo] +-------------------------------+
     [echo] |  GENERATING EAR...         |
     [echo] +-------------------------------+
     [echo] Defining task...
     [echo] Creating services...
     [jwsc] JWS: processing module /HHCServicePortImpl
     [jwsc] Parsing source files
     [jwsc] Parsing source files
     [jwsc] 1 JWS files being processed for module /HHCServicePortImpl
     [jwsc] C:\Demo\WHA\workspace_sdl\hhcService\src\main\csc\ta\ws\HHCServicePortImpl.java 78:8
     [jwsc] [WARNING] - The context path /hhcService specified on port HHCServicePort of web service {http://ws.ta.csc/HHCService}HHCService is being overriden with /hhcService.
     [jwsc] C:\Demo\WHA\workspace_sdl\hhcService\src\main\csc\ta\ws\HHCServicePortImpl.java 87:32
     [jwsc] [WARNING] - Any data in the field "sessionContext" should not be specific to the caller of this service. Values in this field will not be consistent across operations or event handlers on this class.
     [jwsc] JWS: C:\Demo\WHA\workspace_sdl\hhcService\src\main\csc\ta\ws\HHCServicePortImpl.java Validated.
     [jwsc] <WSEE>URIs = [file:/C:/Demo/WHA/workspace_sdl/hhcService/src/lib/hhcService_wsdl.jar]<TylarBindingsBuilderBase.getTylarUris:52>
[AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory C:\Users\palsingh\AppData\Local\Temp\_o4im6

BUILD FAILED
C:\Demo\WHA\workspace_sdl\hhcService\build\build.xml:99: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Total time: 9 seconds
```

Comment: Provide more details about the error

Comment: Added details about the error

Comment: what is line 99 of build.xml ?